# Css Double window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have created a website with many css files and js files. It was previously working fine but i dont know what happened it is now showing two scrollbars , one is of the main window and other in the content. Secondly there is a huge space where the content ends. Its all white space . I have been trying to fix it for a while but no help

[Link of site](http://limousine.avianlimo.com)

You just have to scroll up down and you will see it. it only appears on the homepage. **It goes when i do any change from the borwser in css.**

Comment: You do not give any details nor you show that you tried to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `overflow-y` and `height` rules for html - line 1285 and 1357 in custom.css. I don't even know what could be the function of setting this.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it's not clear to find when you are updating page content, but once you have set your html with some of that rules:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And then extend the updated content of your page, the page increased but 100% mean less then you need. It's getting normal with no-scroll.

I'm not sure that it will solve problem. You have to check out console errors that stops your JS to execute with messages like:

```
getElementsByTagName
```

On line 99 of yours custom.js wich stops to execute on this fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

In your file custom.css in line 13438 **uncomment** this section

```
body, form, select, ul, div{
    /* margin: 0; */
    /* padding: 0; */
    /* outline: none; */
}
```

Actually you have set body outline:0 in custom.css in line 1247

If `outline` will be `none` then all will be fine.